# enable_if with return type for class member function

Tags: c++, enable-if

I was trying out a way to specialize member function based on a class template parameter, without having to use SFINAE on the class (and resulting in either code duplication or creation of another class).

Since two template parameters can't be optional, and argument `enable_if` is frowned upon in guidelines, so I tried out the (remaining) following 2 ways:

```cpp
template <bool boolean = true>
struct sample {
    constexpr typename std::enable_if<boolean, int>::type bool_check_return(
        int s) const noexcept {
        return s + 1;
    }
    constexpr typename std::enable_if<!boolean, int>::type bool_check_return(
        int s) const noexcept {
        return s;
    }

    template <typename std::enable_if<boolean, int>::type = 0>
    int bool_check_template(
        int s) const noexcept {
        return s + 1;
    }
    template <typename std::enable_if<!boolean, int>::type = 0>
    int bool_check_template(
        int s) const noexcept {
        return s;
    }
};
```

[Godbolt link](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/wjIn-w)

On first look, it doesn't seem obvious to me why the return type SFINAE gives the following error about "overloading is not applicable to functions differing only in return type". SFINAE should have ensured only one copy, not two.

Which part of standard am I unknowingly violating? Or is this a compiler bug? Practically, this would not be an issue in C++17 with `if constexpr` (and since one form works, I can simply choose that one).

This error is present in C++11 through C++17, which gives a low probability for the compilers to be wrong about this.

```cpp
error: functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded
    constexpr typename std::enable_if<!boolean, int>::type bool_check_return(
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
note: previous definition is here
    constexpr typename std::enable_if<boolean, int>::type bool_check_return(
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: In such simple cases you could use `if constexpr` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no SFINAE involved here because `bool_check_return` are not templates themselves. They are just regular overloaded functions that differ only in return type. Making them templates would solve the problem by allowing only one of them:

```
template<bool enabled = boolean>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<enabled, int>::type bool_check_return(
    int s) const noexcept {
    return s + 1;
}

template<bool enabled = boolean>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<not enabled, int>::type bool_check_return(
    int s) const noexcept {
    return s;
}
```

Comment: I just tried this in a slightly different way. If for only the second function you write `template <bool enabled = not boolean> ... enable_if<enabled, int>::type bool_check_return` (notice that the `not` is in the template argument and not the `enablie_if` argument) the compiler throws an error saying that the function is redeclared. Why does your version get around that error?

Comment: Does it have anything to do with this? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading

Comment: @MarcoMerlini These overloads differ in return types. While default template parameter is not a part of template signature.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is right. In any case, you cannot overload two functions with the same return type, even though only one return type will be valid after substitution.

From [[over.load]](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.load#2):

> Certain function declarations cannot be overloaded:
>
> - Function declarations that differ only in the return type, the exception specification, or both cannot be overloaded.
> - ...

There is no exception to this rule.